# How to delete particular folder from AWS S3 using amplify in kotlin?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

In AWS console, i have `folder/file` in public older of AWS S3 bucket.
I want to delete folder from that.

I am able to delete particular file from folder like below

```
 Amplify.Storage.remove(
            "folder/file",
            { result ->
                progress.hide()
                Log.i("MyAmplifyApp", "Successfully removed: " + result.key)
              
            },
            { error ->
          
                Log.e("MyAmplifyApp", "Remove failure", error)
            }
        )
```

list of files in folder

```
folder/file
folder/file1
folder/file2
folder/file3
```

But i want to delete all the files from folder.

**Thanks in advance!!!**

Comment: Do you have list of file name stored in S3 bucket ??

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of file names, then you can pass them one-by-one as below.
This will delete the files one-by-one from AWS S3. When all files are deleted,
the folder will be gone, too.

```java
// fileList contains file, file1, file2, file3 etc.
for (String file : fileList) {
    Amplify.Storage.remove("folder/"+file, result -> {
        Log.i("MyAmplifyApp", "Successfully removed: " + result.getKey());
    }, error -> {
        Log.e("MyAmplifyApp", "Remove failure: ", error);
    });
}
```

**Update:**

You can fetch a list of files by folder, and then delete them one-by-one. The
folder will no longer exist when there are no keys under it.

```java
Amplify.Storage.list("folder/", result1 -> {
    for (StorageItem item : result1.getItems()) {
        Amplify.Storage.remove(item.getKey(),
            result -> Log.i("MyAmplifyApp", "Successfully removed: " + result.getKey()),
            error -> Log.e("MyAmplifyApp", "Remove failure", error)
        );
    }
}, error -> Log.e("MyAmplifyApp", "List failure", error));
```

Comment: I want to delete the folder in a single request, not using a file list

Comment: @NensiKasundra There is no method to delete folder in single request. Help your self [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/issues)